# Correct way to set up an AngularJS app i.t.o the Global Namespace?

Tags: angularjs, global

I have inherited an AngularJS app that another developer has developed. And I am now to further develop and support this app.

One thing I immediately noticed, was the way in which he declared his app and controllers, not using the IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) syntax, or assigning the app and modules to variables.

He declared everything in the following format:

**The app module:**

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('app', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngSanitize'

}]);
```

**Example controller:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')

  .controller('newCtrl',
    ['$scope', function($scope) {


 }]);
```

**Instead of using something like this (IIFE):**

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

   angular.module('app')
        .controller('newCtrl');

})();
```

**Or this:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [

    "ngMessages",
    "ngResource",

]);
```

**Will the method used by the previous developer potentially dirty the global namespace with clashing variables etc.?**

As I understand it, and IIFE is useful and recommended for the following reasons:

Why?: An IIFE removes variables from the global scope. This helps prevent variables and function declarations from living longer than expected in the global scope, which also helps avoid variable collisions.

Why?: When your code is minified and bundled into a single file for deployment to a production server, you could have collisions of variables and many global variables. An IIFE protects you against both of these by providing variable scope for each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above nothing leaks to global namespace (except `angular` global which leaks in any case). There are no named functions or temporary variables like `app`.

Angular offers `angular.module` method chaining and inline array annotation exactly to permit comfortable development with no IIFEs or bundling system.

If there is a need to define a variable outside of factory function (this is the case for `constant` service), an IIFE should be used:

```
angular.module(...).constant('constant', (() => {
  var constant = ...;
  ...
  return constant;
})());
```

For highly modular application (one Angular module per file) it is possible to get rid of `angular.module('moduleName')` module getters and rely on Angular modules for dependency handling, this allows to not keep module order when loading or bundling files. This also fits the picture.

Comment: Some questions; the examples I listed of the previous developer, are just the outline. What would happen when there are multiple controllers that are not in an IIFE, and have the same variable names? Would there then be the possibility of variables overriding other in the global namespace? Example: var a = 2 (in a controller called newCtrl) and var a = 4 (in a controller called oldCtrl). Or, would the variables be bound to their specific controllers automatically?

Comment: These variables are not in global scope. They are in function scope. This is the quality of JS functions that IIFE exploits (IIFE stands for immediately-invoked *function* expression, right?). The only way for a variable to leak from function scope to global namespace is to be defined as `window` property.

Comment: I understand the importance of using the IIFE in keeping the variables from leaking, but what if one did NOT use an IIFE, and the variables are simply contained in the controller function - would these variables then be bound to that specific controller function scope, and not be able to leak?

Comment: Yes, they won't be able to leak. It doesn't matter for JS engine if it is a controller function or self-executing anonymous function, they all behave the same way. IIFE is used in the case if there is no *other* function that would keep the variable from leaking (like your last snippet - `app` variable will leak). And Angular was designed the way where the units are always defined inside functions (the notable exception is `constant`, I've mentioned it). I would suggest some reading on [function scopes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) if this concept confuses you.

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation. It does make sense. There are contradicting views on this matter on the net, and it is _that_ which confuses the matter. Some say you have to assign your app to a variable to eliminate the leaking, others say you have to use an IIFE, and others say you don't have to use either.

Comment: There is a context for IIFE buzz. IIFEs (or better, a modular system like Webpack and Browserify) are necessary for a style that involves named functions ([JP style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)). And redundant for a style shown above (consider it vanilla Angular style).

Comment: Thanks. Great resource. :D I think readability of code is essential, especially when working in a team, or taking over someone else's projects. I like designing the apps in a modular style, and using `Controller As`, and `var vm = $scope;`

Comment: You're welcome. I find 'vanilla' style quite readable and perfectly ok for team work (it was propagated by Angular manual after all), it also minifies better than John Papa's. Inheritance patterns turn to be quite limited and weird with 'vanilla', hence JP style is beneficial for OOP development with modular bundles and larger apps (especially ES6/Typescript). It's not that great for smaller projects with IIFEs instead of full-grown modules.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. There is no way you can change this. Maybe you can fork 3rd party solution, or find similar libraries written in a proper way.

**UPDATE**

Or you can use post processors like this:

**gulp:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-iife

**grunt:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-iife

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your response. The question is; Will the method used by the previous developer potentially dirty the global namespace with clashing variables etc.?

Comment: Ofc it would. And I mentioned 2 ways you can automatically wrap all libraries in IIFE

Comment: Thanks, I now understand your reply :). Thanks for the links.